# Haskell Recursion

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I've been working on adding a counter to variables in a given expression and have the following test case:

```
prop_add1 = add (And (Var "a") (And (Var "b") (Var "a"))) ==
And (Var "a1") (And (Var "b2") (Var "a1"))
```

I have been using Pattern Matching and Recursion to try and find a solution. Although I have come a little stuck, I have tried adding the original variables to a list and then using the list to determine the variable name to be output but I couldn't figure out how to correctly implement it and my output just adds a 1 to the end of all variables.

I'm wondering is there a better/easier solution to this?

My Attempt so far:

```
add :: Expr -> Expr
add T = T
add (Var x) = Var (x ++ show (check2(check x)))
add (And e1 e2) = And (add e1) (add e2)
add (Not e1) = Not (add e1)

check :: Variable -> [Variable]
check p = [p]

check2 :: [Variable] -> Int
check2 p = length (union p p)
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more detailed what you're intending to do, what your current solution is and what you don't like about it?

Comment: I'm just intending to output almost the same expression as given in the input, except with numbers assigned to the variables. My current solution - when I encounter a Var I call a function which adds the variable to a list and calls another function which takes that list and just takes the length of that list and adds it to the end of the variable. My theory being as the list grows the number will grow, except this will inevitably lead to "a1" and "a2" instead of just "a1".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep an environment mapping variable names to numbers. Something like

```
add :: Expr -> Expr
add expr = fst $ addWithEnv emptyEnv expr
  where
    emptyEnv = []
    addWithEnv env (And e1 e2)
        = case addWithEnv env e1 of
            (e1', env') ->
              case addWithEnv env' e2 of
                (e2', env'') -> (And e1' e2', env'')
    addWithEnv env (Var name)
        = case lookup name env of
            Just k -> -- stopping here,it's homework
```

I hope I've left enough for you to fill in.

Update:

In your attempt, you don't keep track of which variables you have already seen, so every variable seems to be the first, and every time a '1' is appended. Numbering items is a stateful computation, you must have a record of which variables have been seen so far to assign previously seen variables the old number and know which number to assign the next not-yet-seen variable. So you must carry that record around in the worker. If you already know about the `Monad` class and how to use that, you can implicitly carry it around using the `State` monad, otherwise you have to carry it around explicitly. Then `add` becomes a wrapper that calls the worker with an initially empty state (before the numbering/renaming starts, no variable has yet been seen). The worker then looks at the subexpressions of the given expression (if any) and renames variables and updates the state when a new variable is encountered.

So in the sketch above, we have

```
addWithEnv :: [(String,Int)] -> Expr -> (Expr, [(String,Int)])
```

since we cannot mutate the state, we have to return the new state along with the renamed expression. Now you have to define what the result shall be for each type of expression,

```
addWithEnv env T = ??
addWithEnv env (Var name) = ??
addWithEnv env (Add e1 e2) = ??
addWithEnv env (Not e) = ??
```

The `T` case of course does no renaming and doesn't update the environment. A `Var` has either been seen before, in which case the environment remains unchanged, or not, in which case it is added to the environment. A `Not e` has the same influence on the environment as `e`, and an `And e1 e2` has the combined effects of first `e1` then `e2` on the environment.

Comment: Once you understand this pattern, it is useful to know that it is called "State monad", it is ubiquitous and exists in libraries under the name `Control.Monad.State`, allowing you to write shorter and nicer code (without the syntactic clutter of `env'''`).

Comment: Hmm, trying to work out the pattern - can you explain the use of backticks here? As of now I've only ever seen it applied like 'foo'

Comment: There are no backticks here, only primes/apostrophes, a common pattern to name variables obtained from the original with the same purpose, so e.g. `env'` is the environment obtained from going one step with the initial `env`. Another common method of naming those is `env1`, `env2` etc. instead of `env'`, `env''`, ... Since values are immutable, we have to use new names (one can sometimes use the same name and shadow the previous binding, but that can easily lead to nonterminating loops, so one should be very careful with that).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I see. While your solution seems good it's a little over my head atm, I'll show you what I have initially tried by editing my original post to fit it in.

Comment: Also I kept getting the error Non-exhaustive patterns in function addWithEnv when I finished it, or at least tried to but thanks anyway.

Comment: Expanded my answer a bit. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for adding to it but it's definitely still beyond my comprehension. We've not looked at cases, lookup, Monad or state and from my own research and countless hours trying to get my head around it all I only have a basic understanding of recursion and this question... my head hurts. Think I'll skip this one.